# Putting the display to sleep (⇧⌃⏏/shift+control+eject) in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

Is it possible to write an AppleScript to put the display to sleep (which locks the display if the computer is set to lock on sleep)?  You can do this from the keyboard by entering <kbd>⌃⇧⏏</kbd> (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>eject</kbd>); this leaves all the programs, etc., running, and *just* turns off the screen.

Comment: Perhaps you can remind everyone what that keystroke does?

Comment: Did you see the June 8th answer? I tested, works nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2015-08-23:** This is possible (from the shell) as of OS X 10.9!  [Go see user3064009's answer for the update :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971846/237428)

---

There's no good way to do this; there's [a SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/78222/applescript-to-lock-the-screen) about this same thing.  Depending on why you want this, however, there's one workaround I know: activate the screen saver.  (This is what they suggest over on SuperUser).  You can do this in AppleScript with `launch application id "com.apple.ScreenSaver.Engine"`, or from the command line by running the application `/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine`.  I don't know whether or not this is *technically* documented anywhere, but it's worked for several iterations of the OS now.  It may not do exactly what you want—your screen saver may, for instance, be colorful, which isn't helpful if you want a black screen—but it will be the same in that it does lock the screen if you have that set up.

For a nice catalog of other workarounds, check out [this MacScripter thread](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24825): it documents that

- There's no scriptable way to do this.
- You can't tell AppleScript to `key code EJECT`, as there's no such key code.
- You can use `pmset` to tell the display to go to sleep in one minute, but then you have to wait.
- There's an undocumented IOKit way to do this; there's [a mailing list post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/191807-sleep-display.html) explaining how.

Comment: Is this still true? No way to programmatically put the display to sleep in 2013?

Comment: @Ze'ev: I haven't been looking, but I don't know of any, and a quick Google search didn't turn up anything.  The application you linked to appears to use the undocumented IOKit method that I mention above, so it's nice that someone's packaged it up.

Answer (score 16):

I've been wanting to do this for a while now. I just found out how in the man pages. You can use the following command to achieve instant display sleep. (I have tested it on OS X 10.10.)

```
pmset displaysleepnow
```

(no root privileges / sudo required!)

I'm not sure if this works for 10.9.4 yet but by all means give it a shot!

Comment: Works as advertised in 10.9.5

Answer (score 8):

you can use: `tell application "Finder" to sleep`

Or use bettertouchtool. It is a small app which you can use native functions in addition to applescript.

Comment: `tell application "Finder" to sleep` works perfectly in an AppleScript using Automator, and the behaviour seems to be exactly like what the original key combinations do.

Comment: This is nice to know, but **it puts the whole device to sleep**, not just display(s).

Answer (score 4):

```
do shell script "pmset displaysleepnow"
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an easy way to do it programmatically, but I did find a very small, free app that puts the display immediately to sleep, called "SleepDisplay." (There is another app of the same name that did NOT work for me.)

So you can just

```
tell application "SleepDisplay" to activate
```

Link: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26234/sleep-display

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Awesome job, dude. You found and answered here in just 8 minutes! :D